# How to SharePoint o365 Integrate with Navision On-Premises?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

We'll be developing the **SharePoint o365 portal**, in this portal, we need integration with **MS Dynamic Navision16 on-Premises**. I have no idea how we do this. can some of my friends here who guide me on this topic?
If any Link so please share with me. 
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Dynamics NAV to be available as an app for SharePoint. This means that Dynamics NAV data can be shown in a SharePoint site, and that you can modify the data on the SharePoint site through the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web client.

[For reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/integrating-microsoft-dynamics-nav-in-sharepoint-sites)